# Não consigo encontrar qual Style está separando meus elementos

Tags: html, css

Olá,

Tenho um site que está no ar. Sei que essa dúvida parece bem boba, mas não estou conseguindo encontrar o que está causando um espaçamento entre o Google Maps e meu banner.

Link do site: https://www.bmzveiculos.com.br/

O espaçamento é esse demonstrado na imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma imagem é um elemento inline, e ela tem algumas propriedades default desse tipo de box-model, se vc quer que esse espaço não aparece e como sua imagem tem 100% da largura da tela, basta vc colocar um `display:block` nela que resolve.

Isso vai resolver o problema, adicionando o `display:block` na classe `.banner__two__image` que vc usa na tag `<img>` do banner.

```
.banner__two__image {
    height: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    display: block; /* aqui */
}
```

Veja como resolveu

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado.

Comment: @Jhonny sem problemas meu caro! 

Comment: A alteração já está publicada (:

Comment: @Jhonny parece que resolveu mesmo! Quem bom que deu certo ai!

Answer (score 0):

você tem a `<div class="half__banner">` que contém as duas divisões, a esquerda o mapa e a direita o carro.

dentro da `<div class="half__banner__map">` você tem todo o código apresentando o mapa.

na parte da direita você deveria ter outra `div` para dividir o código da forma correta, mas foi colocado apenas um `<a href....`

O seu código está com essas identificações de divisão.

Comment: Você está querendo dizer que meu `<a>` deve estar dentro de uma `<div>`? Por que isso, por causa do `display: block`? Eu testei e não funcionou.

Comment: Se liga nessa classe .half__banner>* {
    padding: 0;
    width: 50%;
}

Comment: Tenta deixar o width 100%

Comment: .half__banner>* {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}